# Показать наличие ЛОЖЬ/ИСТИНА в ячейках строки и определить долю строки в диапазоне строк

Tags: excel, формулы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить формулу для выполнения условия:

1. Если значение ячейки «Истина», то выводить «1», если «Ложь», то «0».
   Таким образом надо проверить несколько ячеек, чтобы в итоге получилось значение (например, «101» при проверке трех ячеек).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Вторая формула должна посчитать процент каждого из таких значений, например: "000" — 15%, "001" — 20% и тд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат №1 это 4-й столбец. Результат №2 по сути отдельная таблица с процентами по каждому виду 4-го столбца из результата №1

Comment: Уточните задачу. Как понять, какие ячейки? Непрерывный диапазон, разбросаны? Ячейки имеют какой-то общий определитель (например, одинаковый заголовок)?
 Проценты считать где? Число "101" тоже нужно видеть или используется как промежуточный результат и показывать его не обязательно? Покажите пример расположения данных и пример результата.

Comment: Подкорректировала вопрос. Результат №1 это 4-й столбец. Результат №2 по сути отдельная таблица с процентами по каждому виду 4-го столбца из результата №1

Comment: Униккальные коды тоже определять?

Comment: Немного не поняла вопрос.

Comment: Коды, которые получаются в результате (110, 001) могут повторяться. Определять список уникальных автоматически?

Comment: Да повторятся могут. Если это возможно, то автоматически конечно лучше.

Comment: Минут 10-15 придется потерпеть )...

Comment: Хорошо, это отлично)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе три задачи.

1. **Показать "код"**, отображающий положение *ЛОЖЬ/ИСТИНА* в диапазоне (столбец *D* на рисунке).

Если диапазон небольшой, достаточно простой формулы:

```
=ТЕКСТ(A2*100+B2*10+C2;"000")
```

или

```
=--A2&--B2&--C2
```

В первой формуле формируем число и преобразуем его в текст, во второй - логические выражения преобразовываем в *1/0* и объединяем в текст

Для большого применима формула:

```
=ТЕКСТ(СУММПРОИЗВ(A2:C2*10^(СЧЁТЗ(A2:C2)-СТОЛБЕЦ(A2:C2)));ПОВТОР(0;СЧЁТЗ(A2:C2)))
```

2. **Получить уникальные значения**.

2.1. применять доп. вычисления:

== определяем уникальные (столбец *E* на рисунке)

```
 =ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D$2:D2;D2)=1;МАКС($E$1:E1)+1)
```

== получаем список (столбец *F* на рисунке):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>МАКС($E$2:$E$6);"";ИНДЕКС($D$2:$D$6;ПОИСКПОЗ(СТРОКА(A1);$E$2:$E$6);))
```

2.2. извлечь уникальные одной формулой (столбец *F* на рисунке):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС($D$2:$D$6;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($F$1:F1;$D$2:$D$6)=0;СТРОКА($D$2:$D$6)-1);1));"")
```

Формула массива вводится одновременным нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками. после ввода формулы в одну ячейку копировать ячейку на диапазон.

3. **Определение веса (доли)** каждого значения (столбец *G* на рисунке).

Тут просто:

```
=ЕСЛИ(F2="";"";СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$6;F2)/СЧЁТЗ($D$2:$D$6))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете прикрепить файл?

Comment: Если диапазон небольшой, достаточно простой формулы. А если диапазон большой?

Comment: Добавил формулу в ответ

Comment: У меня по этой формуле не получаются такие же значения как в столбце D

Comment: Доработал формулу столбца *D*

Comment: Есть еще вопрос :) Есть 4 ячейки со значениями ИСТИНА/ЛОЖЬ, мне надо сделать еще столбец в котором бы выводилось число 1 или 0. Условие вывода, если хотя бы в одной из ячеек есть истина, то писать 1

Comment: =--(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A2:D2;ИСТИНА)>0)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 0):

Логика такая:

1) Каждую из трех ячеек умножаешь на 4, 2 и 1 соответственно, складываешь полученные числа. Затем применяешь преобразование к двоичной системе, функция такая есть, не помню точного названия.

2) Применяешь `СЧЁТЕСЛИ (COUNTIF)` для каждого варианта, далее вычисление доли каждого из полученных значений.

Comment: 1) Мне нужен не перевод в двоичную систему, а что бы именно проверялось условие. Что бы по этому числу было видно какое условие совпало, а какое — нет

Comment: @Алла, почему же? Как вариант, можно и в двоичную, хотя это сложнее. И без указания формата будет ошибка - игнорируются ведущие нули (например: 001 = 1), поэтому: =ТЕКСТ(ДЕС.В.ДВ(A2*4+B2*2+C2);"000")